# Programatically Reinstall the app in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new in android. Now I am doing programatically reinstalling the application. But I dont know how do this one. I search in google. But I didnt get anything. please help. I tried this way. Please help me.

```
**Deleting:**
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
                   intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:aa.activities"));
                   startActivity(intent);
**Installing:**

Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                    .setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///home/agile/Desktop/ed.apk"), 
                                    "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    startActivity(promptInstall);
```

Comment: What does logcat say when you try the install intent. Does you device actually contain `/home/agile/Desktop/`

Comment: YES.My device contain that one

Comment: Is your device rooted? Also; Logcat please.